# Merging one element into a two-element list

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to find how can do this really quick:

`list = {{a, b}, c, {d, e}, f, {g, h}, i}`

Desired output List is:

`{{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}}`

Looks like simple but it takes me plenty of time to think... sorry if this one has been asked before, I didn't find any answer yet.

Comment: BTW, you cannot set values to `List`.

Comment: Yes, that's a typo, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 15):

Also:

```
Append @@@ Partition[list, 2]
ArrayReshape[list, {3, 3}]
SequenceReplace[{{x_, y__}, z_} :> {x, y, z}]@list
Flatten /@ Partition[list, 2] (* thanks: Okkes Dulgerci *)
{## & @@ #, #2} & @@@ Partition[list, 2]
```

all give

> {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}

**Update:** You can also use the undocumented 6th argument of `Partition`:

```
Partition[list, 2, 2, {1, -1}, {}, Append]
```

> {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}

Comment: Out of these 3 methods, I'm guessing that `ArrayReshape` would be the most efficient, right?

Comment: Thank you! Great answers!

Comment: @SjoerdSmit, sorry for late response. Yes, based on limited tests `ArrayReshape` and  `Append+Partition` combination are the fastest of the four methods.

Comment: `Flatten /@ Partition[list, 2]`

Comment: Thank you @OkkesDulgerci.

Answer (score 8):

```
BlockMap[Flatten, list, 2]
```

Of course, the `BlockMap` also can be `` Developer`PartitionMap ``

Comment: This should be the most concise one.

Comment: Thank you, sir!

Comment: I had completely forgotten about this one.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If the input list is consistently dimensioned, then this would work:

```
list = {{a, b}, c, {d, e}, f, {g, h}, i};
Partition[ Flatten[list, 1], 3]
```

I hope that this gets you what you need.

Comment: yes, the pattern is consistent. Thanks for your help, this is work!

Comment: `Partition[Flatten[list], 3]` is enogh

Answer (score 3):

**Method I**

Step by step

```
Cases[list, _List]
List /@ Complement[list, %]
Join[%%, %, 2]
```

give respectively

```
{{a, b}, {d, e}, {g, h}}

{{c}, {f}, {i}}

{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}
```

**Method II**

```
Flatten /@ Transpose @ GatherBy[list, Head]
```

Comment: Wow, nice illustration!

Comment: @leon365 Glad to be helpful. :)